# Translate from MATLAB diag(sqrt(v)) to Eigen in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, eigen

I have the following MATLAB snippet and I would like to translate it to Eigen with C++:

```
>> v=[1; 2; 3]
v =

   1
   2
   3

>> m=diag(sqrt(v))
m =

Diagonal Matrix

   1.0000        0        0
        0   1.4142        0
        0        0   1.7321
```

My C++ code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1> v;
    v << 1,2,3;
    std::cout << v << "\n";

    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1> v2 = v.array().sqrt();
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 3> m = v2.asDiagonal();

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
      1       0       0
      0 1.41421       0
      0       0 1.73205
```

and so it works but I do not like it a lot because I would prefer something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1> v;
    v << 1,2,3;
    std::cout << v << "\n";

    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 3> m = v.array().sqrt().asDiagonal();

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

which does not compile giving this error:

```
/home/aj/projects/test_eigen/test_eigen.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/aj/projects/test_eigen/test_eigen.cpp:10:52: error: ‘const class Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sqrt_op<double>, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> > >’ has no member named ‘asDiagonal’
  Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 3> m = v.array().sqrt().asDiagonal();
                                                    ^
CMakeFiles/test_eigen.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_eigen.dir/test_eigen.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_eigen.dir/test_eigen.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_eigen.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_eigen.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I can get a one-liner

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1> v;
    v << 1,2,3;
    std::cout << v << "\n";

    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 3> m = Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1>(v.array().sqrt()).asDiagonal();

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

but still it seems to me I am missing something or I do not fully understand how to properly write code with Eigen...

Comment: didn't my answer work ? was there any other errors with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work, notice the `.matrix()` to convert back from ArrayWrapper to Matrix :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main()
{
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 1> v ;
    v << 1, 2, 3;
    Eigen::Matrix< double, 3, 3> m = v.array().sqrt().matrix().asDiagonal());

    std::cout << m << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why dis you add the multiplication by Identity, simply do `v.array().sqrt().matrix().asDiagonal()` or `v.cwiseSqrt().asDiagonal()`.